# To POST a file to a REST api directly from a URL without writing to disk in java

Tags: java, file, rest, post

I am trying to POST a file object to a REST api without writing to the disk.
The file object will be available to me as an http url.

Is there anyway I can send the file object to REST without saving it to the disk temporarily.

Comment: You will have to hold the byte content of file in memory but that will very soon eat up your memory.

Comment: Can I hold only a part of the file in memory and send it in chunks?

Comment: Yes you can but then your client and server will have to intelligent enough to process the chunks.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to send ur file from Angularjs or some other technologies. then receive in REST controller, send to dao layer. after you have to convert the file to bytes  **file.getBytes()** and you can populate the file temprarly.

Comment: Where does DB store the file? Is it not on disk?

Comment: you write your file on the disk. whereever you want. here i am storing the file DB

Comment: Just for your knowledge, RDBMS also sits on file system, it just structures the data in relational form.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use

```
@REquestMapping(value = "{id}/file/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void uploadFile () {
// write your post method here
}
```